# Allowing users to upload files through website | PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

Ok so I followed a [tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) that taught me how to build a simple upload system on my website. Well I'm getting errors instead...

I have a form that allows the user to select the file they want to upload:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="studentAccess/files/uploader.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />

    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />

</form>
```

And this PHP script that is supposed to do all the work. Now I am slightly confused on the tutorial, I'm not sure if this script should be split into two different files or be in the same file as it is right now.

```
<?php

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "/studentAccess/uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

$target_path = "/studentAccess/uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?>
```

The script above is placed inside the `Files` folder which is inside studentAccess

The folder I am wanting to store the uploaded file is inside studentAccess and called `uploads`

```
studentAccess
  |
  | files 
  | |
  | | uploader.php *this is where the script is located to upload file*
  | |
  | uploads
  | |
  | | *this is the folder where I want to store the uploaded files*
  | |
```

Above is the folder layout of where everything is located. The reason I'm including this is because I'm not sure if it is laid out correctly. Does the `uploader.php` file need to be in the same folder the uploads are stored?

When I run the script (i.e. Upload a file using the form and hitting Upload File button) I receive three errors displayed directly in the browser window.

`Warning: move_uploaded_file(/studentAccess/uploads/NHSHandbook1314.doc) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/www/usd309bands.org/studentAccess/files/uploader.php on line 14`

`Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpRpP6uz' to '/studentAccess/uploads/NHSHandbook1314.doc' in /home/www/usd309bands.org/studentAccess/files/uploader.php on line 14`

And finally the error that is generated by the script itself

`There was an error uploading the file, please try again!`

So I am really not sure what I am doing wrong, It appears to me that it is having problems moving the uploaded file to the uploads folder. But I'm really not sure what I need to do to fix the problem. **I did check and `file_uploads` is turned on within my server.**

I hope I have described my question in detail enough to get help. I hope it was laid out in a readable format. I am really needing some help.

Comment: For one thing, you're defining `$target_path = "/studentAccess/uploads/";` twice. Remove the second one.

Comment: Try running the upload form (and handler in same) from your root and setting it up like this `$target_path = "studentAccess/uploads/";` without the starting forward slash, see if that works. And see if the folders exists, and are writeable.

Comment: That is why I'm not sure if I need too make two files for those or not. If you look at the tutorial the way I have it is how it puts it I believe.

Comment: The tutorial which I know very well, does not make a mention of an opening/starting slash. You may have a path issue. Try uploading to a single created sub-folder instead of two and without the starting forward slash. I.e.: `$target_path = "studentAccess/";`

Comment: try removing the `/` at the beginning of target path

Comment: @LiamAllan I said that already.

Comment: @fred sorry, im viewing on ps3, pretty slow to type :)

Comment: When using absolute paths, you may have to use something to the affect of `/user/your_space/public_html/uploads/` but not for relative paths, and that's what may be the issue here.

Comment: I have tried everything that has been commented or placed in an answer as of **3:57 PM CST** and the problem is not fixed.

Comment: @MitchEvans Remove one of your `$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);` you're also defining that twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might be a folder permittion restriction, try making the target folder 777 (read - write - execute via your ftp program) and see if it works. I strongly recommend you to use php's ftp functions to upload files rather than the move_uploaded_file method.

### UPDATE

try changing target path from $target_path = "/studentAccess/uploads/"; to $target_path = "../uploads/";

Comment: A. I changed both the `files` and `uploads` folders to 777 and it still did not work. B. This is the first tutorial I could find. I have **never** done this before at all.

Comment: If you update this answer with a tutorial for php's ftp functions to upload files that works, I will accept answer

Comment: try changing target path from $target_path = "/studentAccess/uploads/"; to $target_path = "../uploads/";

Comment: Place that in your answer and I will accept it, because that made it work! :)

Comment: @MitchEvans That's exactly what I posted, but do accept Nick's answer. Glad to know it worked out. cheers